# What call to action to use on a button that sends an e-mail with order details?

Tags: buttons, user-behavior, copywriting, labels, call-to-action

On a website you can use your e-mail address to view your current order status. No personal identifiable information is displayed. However, you can let the website resend the full order confirmation to your e-mail address (only with same address used to place to order).

What call to action should this button be? The email is automatically sent once you click the button.

'Request Order confirmation e-mail'
'Send me another Order confirmation e-mail'

All options I have considered are quite lengthy. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you assume it is a problem to have a longer label on a button, if that makes it clear what that button does?

Answer (score 6):

"**Resend order confirmation**" seems the clearest from your description.

You have already sent it, so 'request' wouldn't be a good choice as it implies that it has not been sent before.

'Send me another' is clear but too long as it has the same meaning as 'resend'.

Additionally, you don't have to specify 'email' unless there are multiple communication methods that could be used for an order confirmation.

Comment: I would understand “Resend order confirmation” as “Resend the order confirmation to the site”. Whereas in fact it would be the contrary.

Answer (score 2):

You could add some text outside the button within it's context. In that way you can combine a strong and short call to action with a clear desription of it's functionality.